# Is there any way to introspect a TSQL procedure for tables and columns accessed by it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, procedure, introspection

I find myself needing to document all tables and columns that are accessed by a large number of stored procedures in SQL Server.  I can search for stored procedures that have this or that text in the body but that isn't what's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to find stored procedure dependencies.  A cursory google search will land you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345404.aspx

> Using SQL Server Management Studio
>
> To view the dependencies of a procedure in Object Explorer
>
> In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine and then expand that instance.
>
> Expand Databases, expand the database in which the procedure belongs, and then expand Programmability.
>
> Expand Stored Procedures, right-click the procedure and then click View Dependencies.
>
> View the list of objects that depend on the procedure.
>
> View the list of objects on which the procedure depends.
>
> Click OK.

or using SQL:

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('table name', 'OBJECT');
```

etc

To do *all* stored procedures you could write a join on `sys.object` to plug into the DMV listed above, with some potential tweaking... but it's definitly doable.  Think there's probably some SSMS addons to do it as well.  Red Gate maybe?

Comment: Neither of these will be 100% accurate though thanks to Deferred Name Resolution. If you create a procedure that references a table that doesn't exist neither of these methods will return that reference. This will get you the 99% to be sure though.

Comment: I take that back. I think that sql server has gotten better about updating dependencies and tracking them even for objects that don't yet exist. This has not always been the case and I was surprised yet happy to see.

Comment: there might be some issues with dynamic sql stored procedures as well.  Not positive on that one anymore - i know it used to be problematic and i guess still would if it just took in a @param of sql (yuck!)

Comment: Of course this will not work if you use dynamicSQL and pass in the table names or columns as there is no way to know them in advance.

Comment: I have used the "View Dependencies" functionality of management studio however it is only showing a small portion of the actual dependencies.  I'm not sure why the information return is so limited.  

Attempting to query the dependencies results only in errors and I assume this is because I do not have adequate permissions.

I did not want to go the route of C# and the TSqlParser but I might be forced to since some permissions will not be possible to obtain.

Comment: You could try (the free) SQL Search, which just looks for your specified text in the objects. It might come up with false positives though.